# Erlang Amazon Web Services (AWS) EC2 API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, erlang

I have a problem with the AWS EC2 API. I have used `erlawys` and `erlcloud` without any result. With erlawys I create the model, but when I execute

```
aws_ec2_test:test_simple(Key, AccessKey, Model).
```

I receive the error

```
Failed in calling #Fun<aws_ec2_test.0.112913818> on count 100 from 100 to 0.
```

The output of `aws_ec2_xml:describe_image` is:

```
aws_ec2:describe_images(Key, AccessKey, Model).
** exception error: undefined function http:request/1
     in function  aws_ec2_xml:describe_images/5 (../src/aws_ec2_xml.erl, line 364)
     in call from aws_ec2:describe_images/6 (../src/aws_ec2.erl, line 222)
```

The function `http:request/1` is obsolete.

Comment: I replace http:request with httpc:request(). aws_ec2:describe_images work.

Comment: Command "aws_ec2:run_instance(Key, AccessKey, Model,InstanceID)."
 return
"{error,[{exception,{error,"unknown tag: Response"}},
        {stack,[undefined]},
        {received,{startElement,[],"Response",[],[]}}]}"

Comment: It's proper in StackOverflow to answer your own question and accept it. That will help others with same problem as you.

Comment: Yes, but first is necessary to solve problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use erlcloud instead of erlawys, because it is very old and It not works fine.
ercloud is very great.
It is possible start/stop/create/delete instances, manage keys, ecc...
This is the git link:
https://github.com/gleber/erlcloud 
I send mail to the developer becouse I have a problem with amazon Ireland.
He sends me this response.

```
start_instance(Ami, KeyPair, UserData, Type, Zone) ->
Config = #aws_config{
        access_key_id = application:get_env(aws_key),
        secret_access_key = application:get_env(aws_secret)
       },

InstanceSpec = #ec2_instance_spec{image_id = A`enter code here`mi,
                                  key_name = KeyPair,
                                  instance_type = Type,
                                  availability_zone = Zone,
                                  user_data = UserData},
erlcloud_ec2:run_instances(InstanceSpec, Config).
```

This is the README file.
https://github.com/gleber/erlcloud/blob/master/README.md